# Core Data `deleteObject:` problem!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, entity-relationship

I have the following entities in core data as shown in the figure below.
[image: Core Data Model]

**The delete rule for all the relationship is cascade.**

Questions:
When ever i delete the any one of the entity object at level 2 and do `[context save:&error];` all other objects in Table Entity1 gets the data fault and the app crashes due to not able to read the Entity1 object any more, giving `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

I am using this code

```
for(Entity1 *entity in listOfEntitys)
{
    if(entity.Relation1)
        [context deleteObject:entity.Relation1];

    if(entity.Relation2)
        [context deleteObject:entity.Relation2];

    if(entity.Relation3)
        [context deleteObject:entity.Relation3];
}
[context save:&error];
```

Its not like I have never deleted any object from core data but this is the only place where problem is occurring. Can anyone Help.

Thanks.
PS. I have seen other questions on SO but none has the same kind of situation as i do.

**Edit:**

**My problem is that when I try to delete any one object from level 2 then all the objects in the entity1 are getting data fault. some thing like this.**

```
Printing description of listOfEntitys: 
(
    "<Entity1: 0x4dc3d80> (entity: Entity1; id: 0x4dc2d60 <x-coredata://DF11191D-0BE9-4A63-955D-0A43153290A4/Entity1/p5> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Entity1: 0x5b06ea0> (entity: Entity1; id: 0x5b077d0 <x-coredata://DF11191D-0BE9-4A63-955D-0A43153290A4/Entity1/p6> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Entity1: 0x4dc2cf0> (entity: Entity1; id: 0x4dc2df0 <x-coredata://DF11191D-0BE9-4A63-955D-0A43153290A4/Entity1/p7> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Entity1: 0x4dc2b80> (entity: Entity1; id: 0x4dc3640 <x-coredata://DF11191D-0BE9-4A63-955D-0A43153290A4/Entity1/p8> ; data: <fault>)" 
)
```

Comment: What are the delete rule(s)? Did you select cascade for the three connected entities?

Comment: yes all the relations have a cascade rule selected....

Comment: I think the inverses shouldn' be set to cascade. Try to set the inverses to nullify.

Comment: Oh because it wasn't that easy to tell what was wrong. Too many guess around, and finding a solution is mostly an iterative process. I just posted my answer, though too late ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001654-SW4)

> If a relationship delete rule is
>   Cascade, then deleting one object may
>   result in the deletion of others.

If you don't want related objects to be deleted when you delete a given object, then the deletion rule for those relationships should be something other than 'cascade'. You probably want 'nullify' instead.

Comment: no i want to delete the related objects, its just that I am getting data fault after deleting any one of the entities...

Comment: If all relationships are set to cascade, then I'd expect `[context deleteObject:entity.Relation1]` to delete `entity`, which would mean that you'd get EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the next line: `if(entity.Relation2)...`. Isn't that what you said is happening?

Comment: Well even if i do `Entity2.2 *entity2 = entity.Relation1` and then delete entity2 object, same thing happens.

Comment: Sorry caleb i didn't get what you said earlier, now it makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Don't set the inverses to cascade, cause it's like a lit fuse burning down in every direction. Set them to nullify.